# Proper metal for turning/milling a ball-peen hammer

Tags: materials, metallurgy

I've got a simple question here.

What material should hammer's head be made of? We're talking about medium sized ball-peen hammer, used for riveting brass, copper, aluminum and steel rivets. I have acess to lathe and miling machine.

I was thinking about using material CK-45 (AISI 1045; Mat. number 1.1191), is it proper to use?

[image]

Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Check out youtube - most hammers are forged...

Comment: See here: http://www.madehow.com/Volume-4/Hammer.html Remember that simply selecting the right material is only half the battle - you need to consider heat-treatment / post-processing, too.

Comment: I know, but I don't have an acess to the forge, unfortunatelly. I won't use it profesionall, but every now and then, I have to rivet something together (such as wooden plates onto knife blade, etc.).
@JonathanRSwift: I know. I will give it to a heat treatment after it's done, and I will leave the treatment to those, who knows how to do it (masters).
First of all, I'm choosing the material.

Answer (score 2):

Carbon steel bar stock you suggest would be fine for a modest size , moderate duty hammer as you describe. As noted,the heat-treatment is more important. Quench and temper, you don't want the face any harder than about H Rc 30. A better choice would be a Ni containing steel for toughness; eg. 4330 /4340. Also, for extreme duty, a forging would be better as bar stock has the risk of longitudinal imperfections ; inclusions of silicates, etc.

Comment: Why not buy one ?

Comment: It's not a problem in money. I'd rather make my tools on my own. Or at least buy an old ball-peen hammer and make own handle.
Why not buying new tools? It's difficult to get tools made from good materials. In old days, it was good(expensive) and bad(cheap) materials for tools, but today nearly everything is really bad and cheap. I want to make a hammer, that will last me and my kids.

Comment: I'd counter that a 'good' material might not last as long as a 'bad' one, that's forged. Finding an old head and re-grinding/polishing it up and making a handle sounds like the way to go to get that 'handmade feel', without sacrificing performance.